# how to create view in athena view using pyspark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I have try to create view in athena using pyspark like below.

```
spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW work.test_view123 AS SELECT emp_name,emp_no FROM  emp.emp_table")
```

But I am not able to see view in work db.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the SDK to get a reference to the Athena API and use it to execute a query with the create view statement.